# Stuck in Teslagrad

Tags: teslagrad

I don't know if it's possible to go forward, I've been trying for an hour and I don't really know how to continue. I tried to go back but as I have died, the objects set up have returned to the original positions so I am forced to go forward.

The map view:

[image]

Here as seen in the second photo, I can access the closest red ones, but that's all I can do.

[image]

And here in the third photo,  I find it impossible also to do anything.

[image]

Comment: The more detail and information you can provide, the better we can help you. As it stands right now, it's somewhat unclear what your problem is.

Comment: As it can be seen in the photos, I don't know how to continue. Not a clue. In the forward option, second photo, I can access the closest red ones, but that's all I can do. In the back way option, the third option, I find it impossible also to do anything.

Comment: I edited your question to have the images embedded in the post (much more favorable than linking to Imgur) and used your comments above in the post -- hoping to get a more favorable response, but feel free to edit it again yourself to clear up any ambiguity. (I don't play the game, so I can't help with a solution.)

Comment: Uau, thank you, I'll try to ask like that in future

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable the blue cloak and blink through. The red blocks on the top and blue blocks on the bottom should keep you above the electric barrier.

[image: Demonstration]